# Rails has_many belongs_to same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to, relationships

So I have albums and album_tags. One album can have many album_tags so that I modified the models:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :album_tags
end

class AlbumTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :album_id, :album_tag_id, :tag_name
  belongs_to :album
end
```

I also added :tag_name to the attr_accessible for albums.
But now I need to insert those tag_name into the _form.htl.erb of th albums_views

I did so several times with nested ressources but this time it's different and my ideas did not work out.
In my new-method I added

```
@album_tag = AlbumTag.new
```

and in my _form.html.erb it looks like this:

```
<%= f.label :tag_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :tag_name %>
```

The log says:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `tag_name' for #<Album:0xe7331c50>):
```

So I tried to add the album_tag object above:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @album, @album_tag]) do |f| %>
```

and then I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_album_album_tags_path' for #<#<Class:0xe755de48>:0xe755b4cc>):
```

So my play was to insert a form_field with values like tag1,tag2,tag3 and so on.
Afterwards I want to pick them up, and insert them in a for each.
But firstly I have to get that field shown without errors.
How do I do that ?

Edit: I just tried to add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :album_tags
```

into my albums_model. Without success

Answer (score 1):

This rails cast goes over nested forms fairly well.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

and part 2:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

From what I can see, you should be using.

```
f.fields_for :album_tags do |builder|
```